# EMT fill capacity and derates mixing 14ga & 12ga

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, nec, emt

I have an existing 1/2" EMT conduit that has three switch runners, a hot for an unswitched outlet, a neutral and ground, for a total of six wires in 14ga THHN, all for the same 15 amp circuit.

I want to add two dedicated 20 amp circuits in the same area and I'm trying to determine if I can run four additional 12ga THHN wires, two hots and two neutrals, down that same conduit?

If I look just at fill capacity, and if my math is right, I'm okay.  I'm using just under 72mm2 of an allowed 78mm2. (It's a ten foot run with one twenty degree bend, so the pull should not be too challenging.)

But since I have more that three current carrying conductors, I think I need to derate my ampacity. At which point I'm out of my league.

Comment: For derate, we need to know how many circuits are active there now (are all 3 switch runners fed from the same circuit, and is it the same circuit as unswitched outlet hot?) Also why are you running a ground wire in EMT?  How do you feel about getting rid of it or changing it to a bare #12 ground?

Comment: Is this to a separate building (e.g. a detached garage)? If so, I don't believe code allows you to run multiple unswitched circuits.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica you got it correct bellow.  All of the #14 belong to one 15a circuit.  Replacing the #14 ground would be a little challenging and it's green THHN not bare.  The electrician who did the initial install for me is just one of those super extra cautious types that ran a ground wire just in case one of the EMT couplings at some point got loose or wasn't acting as a sufficient ground. I think it's a bit much given that the that the building and question is steel construction and every single box and piece of conduit is screwed to the steel structure.

Comment: @DoxyLover, this is a separate steel framed freestanding workshop but it has its own 100 amp subpanel. These are not separate runs to the building but simply within it.

Comment: @KennethBaltrinic All conduit if properly installed, it's fairly easy to pull the wires out.   No professional would ever do some hinky install with a buried elbow that would be impossible to pull.  It's often best to simply pull all the wires, change/add some and pull the kaboodle back in. and reinsert the lot.  Note that if the ground passes through a box, it must stop there and ground to the box.  EMT doesn't require ground but if it's there, it's gotta be done correctly. Reason #4 why I don't bother much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Deal with grounds.

Properly installed EMT provides its own grounding and does not need a ground wire.  So ground wires in those conduit segments should be deleted altogether.  Where ground is required, the presence of 20A circuits will oblige a #12 wire **but it can be bare**.

Note also that any ground wires must go to the metal box first - they are not run "to device first" like in plastic boxes. So where grounds do exist they should go (or be pigtailed) to the optional #10-32 screw on the metal box. Every box has at least one hole tapped 10-32 for a ground screw.  When I do run ground wires, which isn't very often, I treat each EMT segment as a separate deal and run a ground wire box to box and that's it. I do that when I fear the EMT conduit will get hit or damaged.

Devices auto-pickup grounds off the metal box one of several ways.

- Switches just do.
- Cheap receptacles do it via hard flush clean metal-metal contact with bottomed-out screws.
- "Self grounding" receptacles do it via wipers on the mounting screws.

### Back to your wires.

I count three switched-hots, one always-hot and one neutral.

You want to add four wires for hot-ground pairs.

For reasons, 15-20A circuits simplify to "no more than four circuits per conduit". You can grind through 310.15(B)(16), 240.4(D) and 310.15(B)(3)(a) *if you really want to*.  Any circuit served from 120/240V panelboard counts as 2 wires.

When 2 or more wires "split" current any of them is rated to handle, the entire group of wires counts as 1 wire for thermal derate purposes. Why?  Because wire heat is the square of current.  To create an arbitrary "U"nit, count any 1 wire's heat as its amps squared.  So a wire carrying 20A of heat makes 400U of heat. But split it on 4 wires carrying 16, 2, 1 and 1 amps - heat is 16<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup>. That's only 260U, see how quick that falls off?   That means your 3 switched-hots are a nothingburger.

And the same principle applies to 120/240V circuits such as MWBCs. Worst case 20A on both hots, right? 400U + 400U = 800U both wires.  Well, what if the current is 20/16A with 4A on the neutral? 400U + 256U + 16U.  That's *less*, so really - any circuit counts as 2 wires.

Now if you get into 120/208V 3-phase, it's complicated.

So back to simplicity, four or fewer circuits = you're fine.

As far as conduit fill, you have five insulated #14 + four insulated #12 + an optional BARE #12 ground. Punch that into a conduit fill calc but based on my experience you're fine.

Comment: if I'm understanding the derate correctly, it boils down to the fact that I only have three hots because I only have three circuits. All of the #14 hots count as one because they're on the same circuit and, therefore, can never carry more than 15 amps total, irregardless of how it's spilt across individual wires. And a total of 15 amps of current means a maximum of 15 "amp units" of heat. Made that term up, but it doesn't matter. In fact, having that 15 amps distributed across multiple wires is probably even better because it means more surface area for heat dissipation correct?

Comment: In rereading, you already addressed the last point in my comment.  Heat is a square of amps so splitting the same current across multiple wires not just a little better but a lot better...  

Still not 100% on why you emphaisized the ground wire as BARE however.  Mine are green THHN.

Comment: @KennethBaltrinic Yup!    On the bare ground, it's because a bare ground wire has a smaller *diameter* than an insulated one.  It's an easy way to get about 2/3 of a wire of conduit fill :)  Anyway your #14 ground must go if you install any 20A circuits. While EMT doesn't need ground at all, *if there is ground* it must be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually fine. See NEC 110.14(C), you can use the 90°C wire rating as baseline for derating THHN.

So from Table 310.16 you find for #14 and #12 max at 25A and 30A.

Nine conductors 70%, 17.5A and 21A, you are still within 240.4(D) conventional "small conductor" limits of 15A and 20A.

Using a MWBC wouldn't change derate because you would have 5 existing plus 2 new to get 7 conductors which is still 70%, but it would make the pull a little easier. (Assuming single phase linear loads, non-linear would be 5 +3.  So many details...)

Comment: Irrelevant, but "switch runners" is not a common term  you could further reduce fill count if two of the runners are 3-way switch travelers since the de-rate table specifies not to count conductors that can't be simultaneously energized. (Multiple switchlegs still count.)

Comment: I'm sorry, your right.  My old brain sometimes just grabs the wrong word. Everywhere I said runner, I meant traveller.  I expected there was something in the rules about that because it just makes sense.  Thanks for confirming.  Because, yes, one pair of travelers is for a three-way.